# Prevent Child Form from expanding

Tags: c#, parent-child

How can I Prevent my own designed form (child form) from expanding, it changes its original size when being show to a parent

`frmshow1.TopLevel = false;`
`frmshow1.Parent = panel1;`
`frmshow1.Show();`

I've even used

`frmshow1.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(595, 435);`

if I manually change the right size it doesn't show all the data i entered.

Comment: WinForms I assume?  Look for a BorderStyle or Sizable property of some sort on the window - I forget where offhand, been too long since I worked with them.

Comment: yes sir it is WinForms the BorderStyle is **FixedSingle** it is not sizable

Comment: @officepuppy thers an auto size property on the form that by default is set to font i think.you have to disable that.

Comment: @Virgil i've already done that sir.., the auto size properly is false by default

Comment: @officepuppy i was talking about the property called AutoScaleMode(just to be clear),is that what you meant ?

Comment: Yes sir, AutoScaleMode is set to **Font**, I've changed it to None @Virgil thank you sir for the answer., already done it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `AutoScaleMode` property of Your Form to `None`. Its set to `Font` by Default.